# Can I remotely connect to a PC that is on a VPN?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, cisco

With my personnal PC, I used to connect to my WORK PC that was in the workplace building. With my personnal PC, I had to connect to CISCO VPN first, then connect to my work PC.

But we were recently instructed to get the WORK PC from the workplace and install it at home. My work PC is always connected to CISCO VPN in order to work properly.

What I would like to do now, is to use my personnal PC like I used to do to connect to my work PC that is ALSO in my home right now.

Is it possible? Should I also connect my personnal PC to the VPN to remotely connect to my work PC that is ITSELF always on VPN? I'm completely lost

I tried the following:

Connected to my vpn on my personnal PC to WORK PC using microsoft remote desktop - did not work
Connected to my personnal PC without any VPN to my WORK pc that is on vpn - did not work

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to connect as you did before - connect to Cisco VPN in order to connect your personal PC to your work PC. The connection will be encrypted and more secure. It's overkill for two devices on your own home (internal) network, but certainly the secure option.

Comment: Will I be able too thought? Is it possible? because right now, it's not working. And i'm suspecting that it's not working because im on my vpn on my laptop, trying to connect on my work pc that is ALSO on a VPN. I didn't had this issue before because the work pc was in the work building - without any VPN.

Comment: Since your personal PC and work PC are on the same home network, you should be able to remote in from one to the other using your internal IP address. For example, my personal laptop has an IP of 192.168.0.18 and work laptop is 192.168.0.34. Both are Windows, so I use RDP (remote desktop manager) on personal laptop to connect to work laptop using IP 192.168.0.34. However, on your work PC, remote connections will need to be enabled and allowed through firewall. Also, your company may have policies in place to block remote connections, so keep that in mind.

Comment: well it's not working. I called my job and they said it won't work since im on the same vpn that i'm trying to connect too